# FuelUX datagrid filtering

Tags: marketing-cloud

I just used datagrid FuelUX with a couple of select for filtering but, i got the follow problem:

When i perform then click event btnShow's i initialized the properties DataSourceGrid's and i send a filter for ajax request, the first time works fine, but when i change the selected item from the select and i push btnShow button the datagrid reload data but with the same information that the previous filter and no matter how many times i change the selected item from select control in the datagrid i got the same information.

Regards

```
$("#btnShow").on("click", function () {

        var dataSourceGrid = new DataSourceGrid({
            filter: { ID: JSON.stringify(parseInt($("#cboSelect").val())) },
            url: "StudentList.aspx/GetStudent", columns: [{
                property: 'IDStudent',
                label: 'ID',
                sortable: true,
                cssClass: "text-center"
            }, {
                property: 'Name',
                label: 'Name',
                sortable: true
            }],
            formatter: {}
        });

        var grid = $('#grdItems');

        grid.datagrid({
            dataSource: dataSourceGrid
        });

        grid.datagrid('reload');
});

var DataSourceGrid = function (options) {
    this._url = options.url;
    this._columns = options.columns;

    if (options.formatter != undefined) {
        this._formatter = options.formatter;
    }

    if (options.filter != undefined) {
        this._filter = options.filter;
    }
};

DataSourceGrid.prototype = {
    columns: function () {
        return this._columns;
    },

    data: function (options, callback) {
        var self = this;

        var ajaxParam;

        _optionsGrid = options;
        _callbackGrid = callback;
        _formatterGrid = self._formatter;

        ajaxParam = {
            type: "GET",
            url: self._url,
            data: self._filter, //this parameter never change after the first time
            method: CallbackGrid // this is my callback function to format datagrid(search, pagination, etc)
        }

        ajaxRequest(ajaxParam); //Here is my ajax request
    }
};
```

**UPDATE:**
I've been checking the loader.js file and i think the problem is in $.fn.datagrid. The option param have the datasource property and inside that, the filter property, the first time data is undefined and perform `data = new Datagrid(this, options)` and load the filter that i sent, but the next time, data change to not undefined and it never perform `data = new Datagrid(this, options)` again and never change the filter value. I don't know how to solve this because this code is high level javascript for me :p.

I hope this help, regards.

```
$.fn.datagrid = function (option) {
    return this.each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var data = $this.data('datagrid');
        var options = typeof option === 'object' && option;

        if (!data) {
                $this.data('datagrid', (data = new Datagrid(this, options))); //only the first time load the filter value
            }
        if (typeof option === 'string') data[option]();
    });
};
```

Comment: Welcome to salesforce.stackexchange, is your question or issue specificly related to exacttarget ?  If it is a javascript question not specific, you may get a better answer at stackoverlfow.com.

Comment: Hi Samuel. This is not a Javascript question, it's a functionality problem about FuelUX datagrid

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem in your case is how you define the filter in the event handler. Can you try replacing it with the function call instead?

What I believe is happening is that when event handler evaluated you end up passing one value which would be your first initial filter criteria.

**UPDATED**
I don't have a working sample but my thinking was around following

Wrap ID retrieval for the filter into function:

```
var fnGetFilterID = function() {
    return parseInt($("#cboSelect").val());
};
```

And then in the handler use function in grid initialization call:

```
$("#btnShow").on("click", function () {

    var dataSourceGrid = new DataSourceGrid({
        filter: { ID: JSON.stringify(fnGetFilterID()) },
        ...
    });
    ...
});
```

Comment: Can you provide any code for this solution?

Comment: Updated my answer to include the code sample.

Comment: Hi guys, i updated my question. I test with @vlad code sample and it didn't works.

Comment: Would be nice to follow up this question. Did you find out the solution yet?